# iOS8 CLLocationManager returns Null in Background State

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

in iOS8 when i m putting my app in back ground the CLLocationManager returns Null in location ,i have also unable Location updates in Background Modes and also do requestAlwaysAuthorization

```
    CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: can you please confirm if you have place NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your plist and use delegate - - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

Comment: yes i have implemented that both the things..it works fine in my iOS7 device but not in iOS8

Comment: I have implemented same things and its work fine for me in background mode. Please check few things , you have strong reference of CLLocationManger . Create property in header .

Comment: @Santu C ...after making it property in header. CLLocation *CurrentLocation sometimes getting null.

Comment: Please try with in this way @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

Comment: Or can you please post full method code   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

Comment: Santu C is right,you have to put `CLLocationManager` into header file as a property, not a local variable.That should fix your problem.

Comment: @Santu C & @ Benson Tommy sorry for late replay ..i want to implement background functionality in one of my project so i have made demo for background and in this demo only i assign the last location  in  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{ self.CurrentLocation = [locations lastObject];
}

Comment: did you try with CLLocationManager with strong reference

Comment: @Santu C..yes i have also try with that..i have putted nslog in didUpdateLocations but it does not print anything so i have also try with another thing that when on buttons click i have call method on nstimer and on that method calling while app goes into back ground i do code as evry time in lm trying to get new location and then try nslog..but does not work..:(

Comment: @Santu C..can u please share ur code it might help me..

Comment: @JaydeepChauhan In my project there have lots of thing , let me write a demo project for you . I will share with you later of day.

Comment: @Santu C..thnx buddy..

Comment: @Santu C..problem solved...i have put all above things in view didLoad..which i have wrote in function..about  CLLocationManager *lm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below code for getting location on background mode -

Please enter text for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist file .

Please select location updates on background mode from project settings -

[image]

**AppDelegate.h**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  LocationTest
//
//  Created by Santu C on 28/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@property(strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  LocationTest
//
//  Created by Santu C on 28/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize locationManager;

#define CONST_TIME_INTERVAL 60.0

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self location];



    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}



-(void)location
{


    NSLog(@"location called");

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}


- (void)startUpdatingLocation
{
    NSLog(@"startUpdatingLocation called");

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{


    NSLog(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations");

    CLLocation *newLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];


    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);



}




- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

     [self startUpdatingLocation];
}



@end
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

do put code in viewDidLoad about CLLocationManger

```
CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
lm.delegate = self;
lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[lm requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[lm startUpdatingLocation];
```

Problem solved..